# Maven - how to manage multiple jar with dependencies in common

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I've got a big project which is composed of several smaller projects, each one with a `pom.xml`. Some projects are dependencies of others. The way I made it work is in producing a few independent shaded `jar` and `war` files thanks to maven.

The problem I'm encountering is that I've got a new custom project that is dependent on classes from the main project. The matter is that this project contains a custom class and, therefore, the resulting `jar` file is added afterward to the app.

First I thought about compiling the custom project with all the dependencies into a shaded `jar`. However, when running the app, I got a casting error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.some.class cannot be cast to com.another.class
```

I guess the problem comes from the fact that some dependencies are double. The `com.another.class` exists in two shaded `jar` and therefore it is not the same in the custom project `jar` and the main project one. I've got one Java package that is a dependency of the main project `jar` and of the custom project `jar` as well.

Does somebody have an idea of how to make it work? Is there a way to don't include the dependencies in the custom project `jar` and make it clear that it needs to seek the dependencies into another `jar`?

I hope I've been able to make myself understood.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried maven-enforcer-plugin and dependency-management to solve the issues with the multiple versions? 

- https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/ 
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. Maybe the dependency-management page has something to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing: Shaded jars are not meant to be dependencies of other jars.

You can build shaded (or fat) jars to run them as standalone applications, but don't put them into the `<dependencies>`.

If you need classes in several projects, put them into a project or module and compile them as usual jar (not a shaded one). Then you can use it as dependency.

Comment: I can use a class inside a jar as a dependency of a class in another jar; it's what you are saying?

Comment: I am saying that all classes that are used in several projects should be in jar that is _not_ shaded. Don't put shaded jars into the `<dependencies>` section.

Comment: I see; thanks for the advice. But is there a way to use a custom jar as a dependency in another one?

Comment: What is a "custom" jar?

Comment: I created an interface and the user can implement the interface and create a jar from it. This "custom" jar is a dependency of the program. Hence a custom jar as a dependency of another one.

Comment: No problem having jars as dependencies. Just don't use fat jars (shaded jars) as dependencies.

Comment: Cool. Can you explain to me how to load in the code the class from the "custom" jar, please?

Comment: You declare the jar as dependency and then import the package in your code.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Then you need state more directly what is unclear to you.

Comment: The matter is that I don't know how many implementations of this interface there will be; therefore how many jars. Maybe there is none. My question is how to handle that? How to manage my dependencies dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude sub-dependencies in a dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've got one Java package that is a dependency of the main project jar and the custom project jar. Thus I don't think to exclude a dependency will solve the problem because the two jars need the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to select which artifacts go into your shaded jar.
So you can include a group and except some specific artifacts.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
        <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
        <artifactSet>
            <includes>
                <include>org.vaadin.*:*</include>
                <include>com.vaadin:*</include>
                <include>com.vaadin.external.atmosphere:*</include>
                <include>com.vaadin.external.slf4j:*</include>
                <include>com.github.*:*</include>
                <include>fi.jasoft:dragdroplayouts</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler</exclude>
                <exclude>com.vaadin:vaadin-client</exclude>
                <exclude>com.vaadin:vaadin-theme-compiler</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </artifactSet>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```